# React: When to use functions as children and when to use components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im confused as to when a component should be used to render part of a page in react and when a function should be used. As per: [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) functions can be used within the render function which leads to one question:

When should functions like this be used:

```js
                        <> {this.renderAgreementForm(data)}</>
```

In this case the renderAgreementForm function is a class function that returns a large swath of the page's HTML and functionality.

Should this ever be used over a component? Even when said component will not be reused?

Comment: using SFC over class methods is easier to unit test and keeps your class cleaner, IMO

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) The way you've asked your question is asking for *opinions*. Opinions are off-topic for SO. It's probably possible to edit the question so that it asks for practical "what are the pros and cons of X vs. Y", although it's tricky to do that without getting into "too broad" territory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, whether you define a new component for your data or generate more HTML in an existing component is a design decision you have to make on a case-by-case bases. But there are some guiding principles:

- [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - Does the HTML and the code to create it belong to the core responsibility of the current component? If not, create a new one.
- [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) - Would another person be surprised to find the code in the existing component? If yes, create a new one.
- [Open / Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) - Will your current components allow you to extend functionality in the future without changing existing code? If no, re-structure your components.

My personal rule of thumb would be: If the function renders "large swaths of HTML" or does something non-trivial, I'd probably create a new component. I would use the inline functions for something like (i.e. trivial code):

```
render() {
    return <ul>{ listOfFriends.map(this.createFriendItem) }</li>
}

createFriendItem(f) {
    return <li><FriendShortView friend={f} /></li>
}
```

Comment: I like this - great example, in the `createFriendItem` case using a function makes the component code simpler and cleaner, vs `.map(friend => <FriendItem friend={friend} />)`.

Answer (score 0):

Components should be used when you have "repeat code" such as a custom button or listview item. Anything else can be used as a typical function. This helps with readability and makes it easier to know what is page specific vs app "standard".

Answer (score 0):

In the return part of the render function.

```
import ListWrapper from "./ListWrapper";

// components should be used directly

showList() {
   return <li>item</li>;
}

// function or constants should be wrapped with `{}`

render() {
   const inputValue = "value";
    return (
       <ListWrapper>
           { this.showList() } // <li>item</li>
           { inputValue } // value
       </ListWrapper>
    );
}
```